# CLI/C++ named ValueTuple like in C# (.Net Framework 4.7)

Tags: c#, .net, c++-cli, valuetuple

Is there any way to achieve the same in CLI/C++ as the following:

```
namespace Test
{
static class TestClass
{
  static (int a, int b) test = (1, 0);
  static void v()
  {
    var a = test.a;
    var b = test.b;
    _ = (a, b);
  }
}
```

}
So is there any way to create an ValueTuple with other names than Item1 and Item2 in CLI/C++ so it could be used inside C#.
I am using .Net Framework 4.7.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/msdn-magazine/2017/august/essential-net-csharp-7-0-tuples-explained#the-systemvaluetuple-type

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The names of the values are not part of `ValueTuple<...>`.

The names are maintained by the compiler and attributes are added when they need to be communicated to outside code.

Check it out on [sharplab.io](https://sharplab.io/#v2:EYLgZgpghgLgrgJwgZwLQBsoFtgBMrIA+AdtigA5QDGEABACoowCwAUAN5u3e0ACAjADY+AJgZMAwpmTIuPTqx5K+Q2gAoAlsRi0oAGlpadwAJS0YTWgF51/AwAYTAbjnKVw3gBZaANzUnXZQU3Nx8oBF1rcyYAOigXRRClMIjgKItkGBjgBKSlAH0otX1aU1yQgF9AqtYKoA===).

This:

```
namespace Test
{
    static class TestClass
    {
        static (int a, int b) test = (1, 0);
        static void v()
        {
            var a = test.a;
            var b = test.b;
            _ = (a, b);
        }
    }
}
```

will be translated into this:

```
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Reflection;
using System.Runtime.CompilerServices;
using System.Security;
using System.Security.Permissions;

namespace Test
{
    internal static class TestClass
    {
        [TupleElementNames(new string[] {
            "a",
            "b"
        })]
        private static ValueTuple<int, int> test = new ValueTuple<int, int>(1, 0);

        private static void v()
        {
            int item2 = test.Item1;
            int item = test.Item2;
        }
    }
}
```